# Django - query dataset to find latest day and use as filter in one query

Tags: python, sql, django, database, postgresql

I have an app currently which contains a scraper that runs every 2 days. When the app launches I populate a table with just the most recently scraped data (based on the scraped_date).

Currently I am doing this in 2 queries, one to find the latest date and the second to query for the objects, but I am wondering if there is a way to make it more efficient as it currently takes a couple of seconds to run which slows down the webpage load time.

```
Query 1:
last_day = getattr(Posts.objects.latest('scrape_date'),'scrape_date')


Query 2:
    data = Posts.objects.values('col1','col2','col3','scrape_date').filter(scrape_date__gte = last_day)
```

Thanks!